# How does an online market place collect commissions on bit coins?

Tags: transactions

How do online marketplaces that transact with bitcoins take a commission from the sales?

Do they simple accept the bitcoin first, take their cut, and then transfer the remaining proceeds to the seller?

EDIT: I am referring to a website taking a commission of an online sale, not bitcoin exchange charge fees.

Answer (score 0):

Bitcoin exchanges charge fees on trades.

https://www.mtgox.com/fee-schedule

https://www.bitstamp.net/fee_schedule/

Comment: I meant a website like ebay that uses bitcoins.  How does the website get a cut?

Comment: You should edit your question to clarify then, because answers can be removed independently sometimes.